# Can't remove properties with never from filtered type to get remaining keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extract the keys from object A (`typeof MovementState`) that don't exist in my list of string literals in type B (`"Standing" | "Lying"`) into a string literal union (`"Walking"|"Running"|"Crawling"|"Climbing"`).

I have the following code:

```
enum MovementState {
    Standing,
    Walking,
    Running,
    Lying,
    Crawling,
    Climbing
}
type StillStates = "Standing" | "Lying";

type ExcludeProperties<U, V> = { -readonly [P in keyof U]: P extends (V | number) ? never : string }[keyof U];

type MovingStates = ExcludeProperties<typeof MovementState, StillStates>;
```

At this point I would expect `MovingStates` to have the type `"Walking"|"Running"|"Crawling"|"Climbing"` but instead its type is `string`. What am I doing wrong?

Compiled with Typescript 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Exclude` in the mapping to get rid of the undesired properties and `keyof` to just get the keys:

```
type ExcludeProperties<U, V> = keyof { -readonly [P in Exclude<keyof U, V>]: U[P] };
```

Actually, this can be significantly simplified to the following because the internals of the type are discarded anyway:

```
type ExcludeProperties<U, V> = Exclude<keyof U, V>;
```

Also, to add some more type safety you can add a constraint to `V`:

```
type ExcludeProperties<U, V extends keyof U> = Exclude<keyof U, V>;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and the annoying part is after putting your code in I realised I had the exact same line below my testing code, but hadn't noticed it was getting the right results :/. Have my tick!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is contained in original TypeScript doc (in examples to [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html))

```
type ExcludeProperties<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type MovingStates = ExcludeProperties<keyof typeof MovementState, StillStates>;

// MovingStates will be of type "Walking" | "Running" | "Crawling" | "Climbing"
```